# Create shared objects using codeblocks?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, codeblocks, shared-libraries

I'm trying to learn JNI but everytime I try to run the java program, it throws an exception stating that it couldn't find the *.so library in the lib path with I declared when launching - this should happen. I was under the impression that it shouldn't but then I realized that I never made a so file and in-fact I was trying load an executable (Ubuntu doesn't make clear file extensions).

Anyways, how can I compile my cpp files into .so files using code blocks. I've been looking all over and all I've found is complicated gcc commands that I don't quite understand.

Any insight on how to create shared object libs from code blocks would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the object (.o) files of your classes and then use the -shared tag to combine them into a dynamically linked library.
In my experience, Code blocks does not provide the users with the ability to do so. You will have to make use of gcc.

Comment: I just tried gcc shared command: gcc -shared -o hello.so hello.o
It gave an error but I just discovered that CodeBlocks allows you to create Shared Libraries after all. I'm gonna keep trying these gcc commands. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I am not particularly sure about this, but try gcc -shared -o libhello.so hello.o and let me know what it returns.

Comment: That returns:
/usr/bin/ld: hello.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
hello.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Just tried making a random shared library not related to my current project, it all works but when I try to include <iostream> is gives that error.

Comment: Well, I finally got this to work on windows (DLLs) and sadly I need to somehow make 64bit dlls to go with my 64bit JRE. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it under Linux fedorra with a shell script `compile_shared.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
g++ -I ./include/ -c -fPIC src/MyClass.cpp -o so/MyClass.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,lib_MyClass.so -o so/lib_MyClass.so  so/MyClass.o
```

in the root folder and adjusting the build options in Codeblocks, such that the script is executed after the built.

Codeblocks

- Project -> Build options ...
- Select cpp in tree view on the left
- Pre/post build steps
- add "xterm -T bash ./compile_shared.sh" in the Post-build steps textfield

This compiles the File `./src/MyClass.cpp` to `./so/MyClass.o` and in a next step to `./so/lib_MyClass.so`.